# OAuth2AccessToken not set in Oauth2ClientContext after login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm having some difficulties to get [client token relay](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.M5/single/spring-cloud.html#_client_token_relay) working with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 and Spring Cloud Finchley M5. Please find the example code on github: https://github.com/hansvanbeneden/oauth-example

I have configured the oauth2Login like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

and the client registration repo like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class OAuth2LoginConfig {

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.myWebsiteClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration myWebsiteClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("myauth")
                ...
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restOperations(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), oauth2ClientContext);
    }

    private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {
        ClientRegistration myauthClient = myWebsiteClientRegistration();
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        resource.setScope(new ArrayList<>(myauthClient.getScopes()));
        ...
        return resource;
    }

}
```

I would expect that the oauth2Login somehow sets the OAuth2AccessToken in the Oauth2ClientContext for the OAuth2RestTemplate to use it. But apparently this is not the case, because a UserRedirectRequiredException is thrown when I use the OAuth2RestTemplate.

Is there some magic annotation that I'm missing? 
Can someone please send me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please feel free to correct me if i'm wrong, but basically this is how I understand the issue:

- Spring Boot 2.0 dropped support for spring-security-oauth2, since it now has it's own OAuth support (documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-oauth2login)
- This means you can't use the new oauth2Login configuration and expect the Oauth2RestTemplate to be able to use the oauth tokens set by oauth2Login
- The following project was setup to allow the use of spring-security-oauth2 features in Spring Boot 2.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

To solve my issue I added the spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I removed the oauth2Login and added the EnableOauth2Ssso from the WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Then my Oauth2RestTemplate was able to find the OAuthToken that was acquired by logging in.

```
@Bean
public RestOperations restOperations(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resourceDetails,
                                         OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);
}
```

I have committed this solution on the following branch: https://github.com/hansvanbeneden/oauth-example/tree/implementation-with-spring-security-oauth2-boot